# Error installing scion-browser

Tags: haskell, cabal

I get the following error when trying to install the scion-browser package as follows:

```
% cabal install scion-browser-0.2.9
<snipped>
[23 of 23] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, dist/build/scion-browser/scion-browser-tmp/Main.o )

src/Main.hs:31:24:
    No instance for (MonadException BrowserM)
      arising from a use of `getInputLine'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (MonadException BrowserM)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: maybeLine <- getInputLine ""
    In the expression:
      do { maybeLine <- getInputLine "";
           case maybeLine of {
             Nothing -> return ()
             Just line -> do { ... } } }
    In an equation for `loop':
        loop
          = do { maybeLine <- getInputLine "";
                 case maybeLine of {
                   Nothing -> return ()
                   Just line -> ... } }
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
scion-browser-0.2.9 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do `ghc-pkg list mtl` and `ghc-pkg list transformers` show? And have you an older `haskeline` installed?

Comment: I assume you're just looking for the version numbers.  mtl-2.0.1.0 and transformers-0.2.2.0 and haskeline-0.7.0.0.

Comment: No, I suspected something else, but I have meanwhile found the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [haskeline-0.7.0.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.7.0.0) changed the used `StateT` type. In `haskeline < 0.7`, it used the `Control.Monad.State` module from [mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl), in version 0.7.0.0, `haskeline` dropped the dependency on `mtl` and uses the `StateT` monad transformer of the [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers) package directly. That would in itself not be a problem, since `mtl` now is just a wrapper around `transformers`. However, the module used by `haskeline` is `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict`, while `Control.Monad.State` from `mtl` wraps `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy`. Thus the

```
instance MonadException m => MonadException (StateT s m) where
    controlIO f = StateT $ \s -> controlIO $ \(RunIO run) -> let
                    run' = RunIO (fmap (StateT . const) . run . flip runStateT s)
                    in fmap (flip runStateT s) $ f run'
```

from `System.Console.Haskeline.MonadException` is no longer for the `StateT` used by [scion-browser](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scion-browser).

The easy fix is to constrain `haskeline` to an earlier version,

```
cabal install --constraint="haskeline < 0.7" scion-browser
```

The other fix would be changing the imports in the `scion-browser` source to `Control.Monad.State.Strict` to make it build with `haskeline-0.7.0.0`.

Comment: Upper bound <0.7 added to scion-browser.cabal in version 0.2.10, to be released soon

Comment: @JPMoresmau Good. Will it be better in the long run to switch to `Control.Monad.Strict` to keep up with newer haskeline releases?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, yes eventually we'll move to the new version but let's wait a bit for the dust to settle and ensure there are no issues with that version of haskeline.

Comment: @JPMoresmau Of course. I was mostly interested in whether scion-browser did some knot-tying or other tricks that require a lazy `StateT` or whether it's just a matter of changing imports.