# Error installing scion-browser on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, haskell, windows-7

I am having some trouble installing scion-browser:

> c:>cabal install scion-browser
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   Configuring scion-browser-0.2.9...
>   Warning: This package indirectly depends on multiple versions of the same
>   package. This is highly likely to cause a compile failure.
>   package persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2 requires conduit-0.4.2
>   package persistent-0.9.0.4 requires conduit-0.4.2
>   package scion-browser-0.2.9 requires conduit-0.4.2
>   package persistent-0.9.0.4 requires conduit-0.4.2
>   package persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2 requires persistent-0.9.0.4
>   package scion-browser-0.2.9 requires persistent-0.9.0.4
>   package persistent-template-0.9.0.2 requires persistent-0.9.0.4
>   package persistent-0.9.0.4 requires pool-conduit-0.1.0.2
>   package persistent-0.9.0.4 requires pool-conduit-0.1.0.2
>   package pool-conduit-0.1.0.2 requires resource-pool-0.2.1.0
>   package pool-conduit-0.1.0.2 requires resource-pool-0.2.1.0
>   package resource-pool-0.2.1.0 requires stm-2.3
>   package resource-pool-0.2.1.0 requires stm-2.4
>   package conduit-0.4.2 requires void-0.5.6
>   package conduit-0.4.2 requires void-0.5.7
>   Building scion-browser-0.2.9...
>   Preprocessing executable 'scion-browser' for scion-browser-0.2.9...
>   : cannot satisfy -package-id conduit-0.4.2-c025272176b9b270983e467
>   261997051:
>       conduit-0.4.2-c025272176b9b270983e467261997051 is shadowed by package condui
>   t-0.4.2-0f5630d0055300f13b0cabee16d6043f
>       (use -v for more information)
>   cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   scion-browser-0.2.9 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

Attempting to install scion-browser from the eclipse popup gives me the following error:

> src\Scion\PersistentBrowser\Build.hs:43:1:
>       Warning: Defined but not used: `ghcDbUrl'<br/>
>   [18 of 23] Compiling Scion.PersistentBrowser ( src\Scion\PersistentBrowser.hs, dist\build>scion-browser\scion-browser-tmp\Scion\PersistentBrowser.o )<br/>
>   [19 of 23] Compiling Scion.PersistentHoogle.Instances.Json ( src\Scion\PersistentHoogle\Instances\Json.hs, dist\build\scion-browser\scion-browser-tmp\Scion\PersistentHoogle\Instances\Json.o )<br/>
>   [20 of 23] Compiling Scion.PersistentHoogle ( src\Scion\PersistentHoogle.hs, dist\build\scion-browser\scion-browser-tmp\Scion\PersistentHoogle.o )<br/>
>   [21 of 23] Compiling Paths_scion_browser ( dist\build\autogen\Paths_scion_browser.hs, dist\build\scion-browser\scion-browser-tmp\Paths_scion_browser.o )<br/>
>   [22 of 23] Compiling Server.PersistentCommands ( src\Server\PersistentCommands.hs, dist\build\scion-browser\scion-browser-tmp\Server\PersistentCommands.o )<br/>
>   [23 of 23] Compiling Main             ( src\Main.hs, dist\build\scion-browser\scion-browser-tmp\Main.o )<br/>
>   <br/>
>   src\Main.hs:31:24:<br/>
>       No instance for (MonadException BrowserM)<br/>
>         arising from a use of`getInputLine'
>       Possible fix:
>         add an instance declaration for (MonadException BrowserM)
>       In a stmt of a 'do' block: maybeLine <- getInputLine ""
>       In the expression:
>         do { maybeLine <- getInputLine "";
>              case maybeLine of {
>                Nothing -> return ()
>                Just line -> do { ... } } }
>       In an equation for `loop':
>           loop
>             = do { maybeLine <- getInputLine "";
>                    case maybeLine of {
>                      Nothing -> return ()
>                      Just line -> ... } }
>   cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   scion-browser-0.2.9 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

[Error installing scion-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617335/error-installing-scion-browser)
Suggests to run: cabal install --constraint="haskeline < 0.7" scion-browser

but i get the same error as the first.

> c:>cabal install --constraint="haskeline < 0.7" scion-browser
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   Configuring scion-browser-0.2.9...
>   Warning: This package indirectly depends on multiple versions of the same
>   package. This is highly likely to cause a compile failure.
>   package persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2 requires conduit-0.4.2
>   package persistent-0.9.0.4 requires conduit-0.4.2
>   package scion-browser-0.2.9 requires conduit-0.4.2
>   package persistent-0.9.0.4 requires conduit-0.4.2
>   package persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2 requires persistent-0.9.0.4
>   package scion-browser-0.2.9 requires persistent-0.9.0.4
>   package persistent-template-0.9.0.2 requires persistent-0.9.0.4
>   package persistent-0.9.0.4 requires pool-conduit-0.1.0.2
>   package persistent-0.9.0.4 requires pool-conduit-0.1.0.2
>   package pool-conduit-0.1.0.2 requires resource-pool-0.2.1.0
>   package pool-conduit-0.1.0.2 requires resource-pool-0.2.1.0
>   package resource-pool-0.2.1.0 requires stm-2.3
>   package resource-pool-0.2.1.0 requires stm-2.4
>   package conduit-0.4.2 requires void-0.5.6
>   package conduit-0.4.2 requires void-0.5.7
>   Building scion-browser-0.2.9...
>   Preprocessing executable 'scion-browser' for scion-browser-0.2.9...
>   : cannot satisfy -package-id conduit-0.4.2-c025272176b9b270983e467
>   261997051:
>       conduit-0.4.2-c025272176b9b270983e467261997051 is shadowed by package condui
>   t-0.4.2-0f5630d0055300f13b0cabee16d6043f
>       (use -v for more information)
>   cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   scion-browser-0.2.9 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

I have HaskellPlatform-2012.2.0.0-setup installed and Eclipse 4.2 on a Windows 7 64bit machine. I have also already followed the install instructions of Yesod as on their website.

Thanks
Daneel

Comment: You have broken dependencies. You've installed a newer version of `conduit` that replaced an older version, and now there's dependency hell. I'd suggest just deleting your `AppData\Roaming\cabal` directory and starting over.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dflemstr. After deleting AppData\Roaming\cabal and doing a cabal update the problem still persists.

Comment: Maybe Eclipse uses a different directory than the global `cabal` directory? Otherwise, I don't know what the problem could be, I am not using the Haskell plugin for Eclipse, personally.

Comment: Cabal-install do not store installed libraries in it's dir, only binaries. They are stored in ghc dir, but dropping system ghc dir will make platform unusable.

Comment: Topic starter has broken dependencies. The only reliable way is to drop entire ~/.ghc and rebuild all. So, I recommend 1)to purge platform 2)to purge all `ghc` and `cabal` dirs 3)install platform system-wide 3) run `cabal update` 4) consult mans and make `cabal-install` to install packages on per-user basis by default. 5) install your staff. This will put packages into user ghc-pkg dir, not system one. And do not use any haskell-related package system except cabal on windows. Never. Note: this will deal with broken deps, but different versions of same package may result in bad stuff anyway.

Comment: Thanks permeakra, your comment advice helped a great deal to resolve my package issues. I followed to following steps to resolve the problem:

Uninstalled HaskellPlatform,

Deleted: C:\Users\Daneel\AppData\Roaming\ghc,

Deleted: C:\Users\Daneel\AppData\Roaming\cabal,

Reinstalled HaskellPlatform,

cabal update,

cabal install yesod-platform,

cabal install haskeline-0.6.4.7,

cabal install --constraint="haskeline < 0.7" scion-browser